# Node - go through folder of JS files and extract certain bits

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation

I'm currently maintaining a document of tests as a spreadsheet - so I have 3 columns:

- Filename
- text from an `it` block - its a mocha test `it('does this thing', function(){ ... })`
- A description - that i'm writing.

However I don't like the idea of this as its time consuming to maintain.

Is it possible to automate this, i'm thinking some npm package exists. So this would run through a folder, get the filenames and look into each JS to gather information after some defined string regex. For example look for any text after `//DESCRIPTION` and `it(` - like this:

```
//DESCRIPTION: Some text here
it('does this thing', function(){ ... })
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **esprima** to get the **AST**, filter out the test blocks you want, generate source code by **escodegen**

Here is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const esprima = require('esprima')
const escodegen = require('escodegen')


function walkSync (dir) {
  return fs.statSync(dir).isDirectory()
    ? Array.prototype.concat(...fs.readdirSync(dir).map(f => walkSync(path.join(dir, f))))
    : dir
}

const result = walkSync('./test').map(path => {
  const ast = esprima.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8'))
  ast.body = ast.body.filter(elem => {
    return elem.type === 'ExpressionStatement'
      && elem.expression && elem.expression.callee
      && elem.expression.callee.name === 'it'
  })
  const code = escodegen.generate(ast)
  return {
    path,
    code
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

What the test folder structure look like:
[image]

What test case look like:
[image]

What execution result look like:
[image]